# $_POST setted after I unset it

Tags: php, post

Here, I have made validation for checkbox. 
First when I select on submit button, it shows validation error.
After that when I click on "selectall" button, it goes in update query that is on submit button.
That mean, $_POST is setted. 
I have unset that submit button for that, although it is going in update query through "selectall" button.
Why this is happening?

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_POST['processorder']))
{
        echo "hello";exit;
        $chk = $_SESSION['id'];

        $query="update order_details set process_order='1' where id IN(".implode(',',$chk).")";
        //mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    unset($_SESSION['id']);
    unset($_SESSION['on']);
    $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = 'Order processed successfully.';
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die();
}

if(empty($_SESSION['id']) && $_POST['processorder'])
{
    print_r($_POST);
    $error = "Please select an Order(s)..!!";
    unset($_POST['processorder']);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($_POST);

}

<input type="button" name="selectpage" value="Select All Page" onclick="selectall()"/>

<input type="submit" id="processorder" name="processorder" value="Process Order" class="submit-green"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="id[]">
```

Comment: Have your code enter into `if(empty($_SESSION['id']) && $_POST['processorder'])` condition

Comment: @Saty : Yes it goes...

Comment: Have you want to unset all post value???

Comment: Ya i did that and it also unseted. Although it is going in first condition of update query. 
As you see, I have checked by print_r($_post).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to unset all `$_POST` values you shouldn't just unset `$_POST['processorder']`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // to unset processorder
    unset($_POST['processorder']);
    var_dump($_POST);

    // To unset all $_POST values
    unset($_POST);
    var_dump($_POST); // Will return bool(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've `unset($_SESSION['id']);`, `if(empty($_SESSION['id']))` will return TRUE.

This happens because `if(empty(unset($var)))` will always return TRUE.